# Django Rest Framework custom validation errors

Tags: validation, field, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to customize the default validation errors of DRF (3.x) for an account model.
My goal is to write a validation function in order to send back a customized error message.

I've tried the following:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password',)

    def validate_password(self, value):
        """
        Validate Password.
        """
        if not value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password cannot be empty!")
        elif len(value) < 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Password to short...")
        return value
```

The the length validation works fine, but the 'password is empty' validation is never thrown because the default error ('password', [u'This field may not be blank.']) is thrown before.

Is there any option to disable default errors or to force validation by my custom function first?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override the validation errors on a per-field basis by setting [the `error_messages` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#error_messages) when initializing the field. You need to pass a dictionary with the key being the error message name, and the value being the custom text for the error message.

In your case, you are looking to implement two error messages: [`required`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/fields.py#L152) and [`min_length`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/fields.py#L551). You may also need to override [`blank`](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/e39d8410de26003421f7e644f9206833a3b9bbe0/rest_framework/fields.py#L549), which is triggering your current error, unless you set `allow_blank=True` on the field.

So with those changes, your serializer would become

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True,
        required=False,
        min_length=5,
        error_messages={
            "blank": "Password cannot be empty.",
            "min_length": "Password too short.",
        },
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password', )
```

I've replaced your `len` check with [the `min_length` argument](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield) on the password field.

This offloads all of your validation to Django REST framework, which should make upgrades easier in the future. You can still override `validate_password` if you need additional custom validation, but for now I've removed it since it would be empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I want to return language specific error messages, I thought it would be a better idea to call a function, which handles the different messages for the same error. Is there any possibility to call a function from the error_message argument?

Comment: I would recommend looking into [Django's translation utilities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/). It is what [DRF will be using for translations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27955028/359284), and I've been told it works well. The other option is to [override the exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) and manually do the translations there.

Answer (score 5):

Found a solution:

I had to validate the values with the to_internal_value function because validation is run in a specific order (thanks to Kevin Brown):
[order of validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591574/order-of-serializer-validation-in-django-rest-framework)

Now my improved code is as follows:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'password',)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        password = data.get('password')
        """
        Validate Password.
        """
        if not password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password cannot be empty!'})
        elif len(password) < 5:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Password to short...'})

        return {
            'password': password
        }
```

I hope this post is useful for somebody :)

Comment: Why does it work....? It seems that the `validate_emtpy_values` is executed before `to_internal_value` in `run_validation` function in the [source code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L360)

Comment: @soooooot `serializer.to_internal_value` should be called before `serializer.run_validation`. I've updated the [order of validation answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27591842/359284) to include links to the source code, so you can trace the calls.